# How to use Join with like operator and then casting columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables with these columns:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp 
(
    Phone_number varchar(100) -- example data: "2022033456"
)

CREATE TABLE orders 
(
    Addons ntext -- example data: "Enter phone:2022033456<br>Thephoneisvalid"
)
```

I have to join these two tables using 'LIKE' as the phone numbers are not in same format. Little background I am joining the #temp table on the phone number with orders table on its Addons value. Then again in WHERE condition I am trying to match them and get some results. Here is my code. But my results that I am getting are not accurate. As its not returning any data. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am using SQL Server.

```
select
    * 
from
    order_no as n
join 
    orders as o on n.order_no = o.order_no
join
    #temp as t on t.phone_number like '%'+ cast(o.Addons as     varchar(max))+'%'
where
    t.phone_number = '%' + cast(o.Addons as varchar(max)) + '%'
```

Comment: This question is not clear.  Please include sample data from the two tables involved in the join.

Comment: Using `ntext` makes things difficult as not every text-processing function supports it. `ntext` is deprecated and you should use `nvarchar(max)` anyway. Are you able to change your table schema to use `nvarchar(max)` instead?

Comment: If you have two tables, why does your query contain three?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use LIKE statement in the JOIN condition. Please provide more information on your tables. You have to convert the format of one of the phone field to compile with other phone field format in order to join.

Comment: This is just wrong.  `LIKE` can, of course, be used as a `JOIN` condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `join` condition is in the wrong order.  Because your question explicitly mentions two tables, let's stick with those:

```
select * 
from orders o JOIN
      #temp t
      on  cast(o.Addons as varchar(max)) like '%' + t.phone_number + '%';
```

It has been so long since I dealt with the `text` data type (in SQL Server), that I don't remember if the `cast()` is necessary or not.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do everything in a single top-level query, you should apply a transformation projection to your `orders` table and use that as a subquery, which will make the query easier to understand.

Using the `CHARINDEX` function will make this a lot easier, however it does not support `ntext`, you will need to change your schema to use `nvarchar(max)` instead - which you should be doing anyway as `ntext` is deprecated, fortunately you can use `CONVERT( nvarchar(max), someNTextValue )`, though this will reduce performance as you won't be able to use any indexes on your `ntext` values - but this query will run slowly anyway.

```
SELECT
    orders2.*,
    CASE WHEN orders2.PhoneStart > 0 AND orders2.PhoneEnd > 0 THEN
        SUBSTRING( orders2.Addons, orders2.PhoneStart, orders2.PhoneEnd - orders2.PhoneStart )
    ELSE
        NULL
    END AS ExtractedPhoneNumber
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            orders.*, -- never use `*` in production, so replace this with the actual columns in your orders table
            CHARINDEX('Enter phone:', Addons) AS PhoneStart,
            CHARINDEX('<br>Thephoneisvalid', AddOns, CHARINDEX('Enter phone:', Addons) ) AS PhoneEnd
        FROM
            orders
    ) AS orders2
```

I suggest converting the above into a `VIEW` or `CTE` so you can directly query it in your JOIN expression:

```
CREATE VIEW ordersWithPhoneNumbers AS
    -- copy and paste the above query here, then execute the batch to create the view, you only need to do this once.
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
SELECT
    * -- again, avoid the use of the star selector in production use
FROM
    ordersWithPhoneNumbers AS o2 -- this is the above query as a VIEW
    INNER JOIN order_no ON o2.order_no = order_no.order_no
    INNER JOIN #temp AS t ON o2.ExtractedPhoneNumber = t.phone_number
```

Actually, I take back my previous remark about performance - if you add an index to the `ExtractedPhoneNumber` column of the `ordersWithPhoneNumbers` view then you'll get good performance.

Comment: I can not change ntext data type in the schema as it's in the database. Is there any way that works with ntext and I can get the  results/

Comment: @PSri Wrap the uses of the `ntext` column in `CONVERT( nvarchar(max), value )`